# Terminology: Pagraph subject identification prefix text

Tags: writing-style, terminology

Reference books, technical manuals, MIL standards, etc., prefix every paragraph with a short subject identification statement. For example, paragraph 1.3 in the 16th ed. of the *Chicago Manual of Style* (CMoS) begins,

> 1.3     ***Rectos and versos***.  Publishers refer to the ...

Is there a common terminology for the ***bolded and italicized*** (in this case) subject identification prefix text? What is this writing practice called? In particular, does the CMoS define this practice (I've looked extensively in the CMoS but I couldn't find anything).

(FWIW, the MIL standards I checked typically identify this text as "paragraph identification", "subject identification," or "paragraph and subparagraph identifications". But I can't find in other style guides a description for this paragraph summary text.)

Comment: I'm not sure this is about academia per se; your question seems to be more about style terminology and hence off topic.

Comment: Engineers and technical writers commonly use this style. This is a writing style that's sometimes taught to undergraduate engineering students because they will likely see and use it in industry.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is just called the (sub)section name --- as driven by the LaTeX styling used in many STEM disciplines.  No fancier title is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in the software development industry, people usually just call it the *heading* or *header*. But *(sub)section name* is also used, as jakebeal suggests.

However, in my field, the heading is more commonly separated from the rest of the text, as shown below. So this may not be the terminology you're looking for.

> 1.3     Rectos and versos.
>
> ```
>     Publishers refer to the ...
> ```

We do sometimes combine the heading with the rest of the text, as you have it. This might be done at the lowest level, for example, when there's a list of terms with their definition. In such a situation, If I wanted to make it clear that I'm referring to the text in bold, I'd probably say *the heading itself*.